# composer - work with project and dependency at the same time

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have a project that contains a subproject. They are in separate repositories.

In a production environment the subproject would be a dependency of the main project declared in the `composer.json` file.

In my development environment I would like to able to work with both projects at the same time. I don't want to `composer update` my subproject everytime I modify it.

At the moment I have my subproject included in a subfolder of the main project which is `.gitignore`d, in such a way that it is not seen from the main repository but it is seen by the application. This approach poses a series of problems, like:

- I need to have differente `compose.json` in development and in production
- In developmente I need to load the dependencies if the subproject through the `composer.json` of the main project

Is there a way to make composer handle this situation all by itself? Is there some better solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a perfect solution.  The best you can do is to change the version number of your sub-project to the branch you are working on (such as `dev-master`) and run `composer update`.  You can then work directly in the sub-project code in your `vendor` directory.  You can even commit and push your code from there.  The downside is that you have to be careful when you commit your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files because of the manual dev-only changes.  Changes to those files don't happen terribly often, so it's not too bad.